# Remove starting block and ending block behavior with CSS

Tags: css

Is there a way with **CSS** such that:

```
hi 
<div>
  <p>
    hello 
  </p>
  <p>
    world 
  </p>
</div>
baz
```

will render like this:

```
hi hello

world baz
```

whereas with the same CSS this:

```
hi 
<div>
  <p>
   hello world 
  </p>
</div>
baz
```

would render like this?

```
hi hello world baz
```

and

```
hi 
<div>
  <p>
    hello 
  </p>
  <p>
    foo
  </p>
  <p>
    world 
  </p>
</div>
baz
```

would render like this:

```
hi hello

foo 

world baz
```

#### What I have tried

In this fiddle you can see that I was playing around with the first-child and last-child pseudo selectors, but to no avail.

https://jsfiddle.net/lovinglobo/0zbvdpao/

I can not control the HTML rendering of an external library, that's why I am trying CSS voodoo. However, I am not a CSS guru.

Comment: I'd suggest, instead of using CSS, that you consider parsing the data server-side (with php, node, etc...) and then pass on that modified data to the client. In an ideal world how would that returned data be structured? What rules would apply, or should be applied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like this:

```css
div {
  display: contents; /* this will make the div disappear */
  /* display:inline can also do the job but let's learn a new value ;) */
}

p {
  display:inline; /* p as inline */
}
p + p::before { /* add a line break if there is a second p */
  content:"\A";
  white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
hi
<div>
  <p>
    hello
  </p>
  <p>
    world
  </p>
</div>
bar

<hr> 

hi
<div>
  <p>
    hello world
  </p>
</div>
bar

<hr>


hi 
<div>
  <p>
    hello 
  </p>
  <p>
    foo
  </p>
  <p>
    world 
  </p>
</div>
baz
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the previous answer will not work in a wide range of older browsers, including IE3-11 as he's using newer CSS that isn't necessary. You also don't need all those pseudo-elements. Removing margins and padding is optional. I like to remove those to keep the style clean and in case a UA style sheet or 'reset' sheet in the browser has changed those on `p` elements. Number one rule in programming is keep it simple! Second rule is **Always Support Older Browsers**! This version below should work in 99.99% of known browsers:

```
hi 
<div style="display:inline;margin:0;padding:0;">
  <p style="display:inline;margin:0;padding:0;">
    hello 
  </p>
  <p>
    foo
  </p>
  <p style="display:inline;margin:0;padding:0;">
    world 
  </p>
</div>
baz
```

- move these inline styles to classes as needed

Comment: *This version below should work in 99.99% of known browsers:* --> but doesn't produce the needed result .. by the way, my answer is support in all the browsers, I am not using any *new* CSS (if you refer to `contents`, I added that we can do it with `inline`)

Comment: Afif, go to canIuse.com. "display:contents" isn't supported in IE, Baidu, and other browsers. I appreciate your answer, but choosing not to support older browsers in solutions like means that many new developers using that code will have problems later.

Comment: read my answer again where I said : *display:inline can also do the job but let's learn a new value* <-- my solution is supported in all the browser and I am showing a new stuff

Comment: Please test your solution in IE11. It fails. If you want to go back to using "display:inline" and get full credit in your answer, its fine with me. Ill remove my entry if you do. The main lesson for you is stop pushing newer CSS that breaks in older browsers and think about a wider end-user target as a web developer. :)

Comment: It would be nice to support older browsers, but this solution does not work for the first example. It should work for all three. I also need those psuedo elements, because I can not change the HTML.